# Print a output to a log file and also show it

Tags: python, python-3.x, output

I'm looking for a way to print my output prints into a log file, but i want to see also in my pycharm debugger.

I found this but it only prints into the file:

```
log = open("myprog.log", "a")
sys.stdout = log

>>> print("Hello")
>>> # nothing is printed because it goes to the log file instead.
```

Is there any way to to this?

Comment: I would suggest [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)  for this task. For this particular task you would need to implement some [handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#handlers)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid replacing `sys.stdout` if you can, and here you can.

```py
log_file = open('myprog.log', 'a')
def log(text):
    print(text)
    log_file.write(str(text) + '\n')

log('hello')
```

Comment: it works for 1 print, but if i got 10 prints inside my code?

Comment: @LucasFernandes You should be able to use `log()` as many times as you need. Just be sure to call `log_file.close()` when you're done logging at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `logging` module:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='myprog.log')
logging.info('Hello')
```

It is very clean, efficient and prints messages also in the terminal. You can find a very good tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html), with a paragraph about logging from multiple modules.

Alternatively, if you really want to define your own function, this will be usable even when defined in another file:

```
def log_text(log_file_path, verbose, text):
    """
    Function to print text in console and add it to a log file.

    :param log_file_path: path of the log file
    :param verbose: boolean parameter, when True text is printed to terminal
    :param text: string of the message to print and write
    :return: nothing
    """

    if verbose:
        print(text)

    with open(log_file_path, "a") as lf:
        lf.write(text + "\n")

    return
```

Note that `verbose` parameter is optional, it is just handy to have this sort of parameter.

You can then call this function anywhere in your code.

Comment: That might be problematic since you open and close the file each time the `log_text` is invoked. What if you write 1millions of lines? Better to keep the file open until you finish logging. Or better use the tool that developed for the task, the logging: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

Comment: @MSH Very interesting, particularly the `Logging from multiple modules`, I ended up here searching for something like that :) Do you want to post another answer? Otherwise I can just update mine in case someone else ends up here as well

Comment: go ahead. (15 char limitation...)